# Run MySQL and SQL database with PHP on windows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I already use wamp(PHP+MySQL) on windows m//c. Now I wan to use SQL database with PHP along with WAMP. Can I use two diff database with PHP on same machine ?

Comment: McDonals? Nah.. Just messing with you. Probably "Machine"?

Comment: @LoganWayne Yeah, OP edited the question after I asked that. The word "machine" wasn't there originally.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, install SQL server database, and change the connection parameter as needed. 
You can even use two databases for one project.
Cheers!

Comment: Can I use both the database at a time ? Without disabling any one service

Comment: @kreya Yes you can. And if you use PDO you can actually connect to both using the same code: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: yeah! Just make sure database services are running in different ports. And to connect with SQL server, please refer:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Comment: @satroy I still think PDO would be a better choice... It sure beats trying to mix two different types of connection API code in your app.

Comment: @Mike. Definitely, PDO is also secure way to connect.